# How to make a structured and localized resource?

Tags: java, android, reflection, resources

I would like to define the possible error messages out of the code - in resources. There is no problem to make them localized. 
But I need also to define for every of them the places, where they will be shown/logged. For example: screen, localLog, serverLog. 
Without localization I could do it so :

```
<!-- every error has a message and boolean keys that allows or not to write the message
        to places serverLog/localLog/Screen -->

<string-array name="error_names">
   <item >no_net</item>
</string-array>    

<string-array name="error_messages">
    <item >There is no internet connection. Check the cables. If they are OK, call your provider.</item>
</string-array> 

<string-array name="output_keys">
    <item >010</item>
</string-array>
```

And I would make a class for error messages with loading all of them into a static map

```
public class ErrorMessage {
    private String messageText;
    private String errorName;
    private ArrayList<String> messageOutputs;
    static List<String> messagesPossibleOutputs=Arrays.asList("Server","LocalLog","TV");
    static public HashMap<String,ErrorMessage> messagesMap;

static public int downloadMessages(Context context){
    String messages[]=context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.error_messages);
    String errorNames[]=context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.error_names);
    String outputKeys[]=context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.output_keys
    messagesMap=new HashMap<String,ErrorMessage>();
    for(int i=0; i<messages.length; i++){
        ErrorMessage curErrorMessage=new ErrorMessage();
        curErrorMessage.errorName=errorNames[i];
        curErrorMessage.messageText=messages[i];
        curErrorMessage.messageOutputs=new ArrayList();
        for(int iKey=0; iKey<outputKeys[i].length();iKey++){
            String curChar=outputKeys[i].substring(iKey, iKey+1);
            if(curChar.equals("1")){
                curErrorMessage.messageOutputs.add(messagesPossibleOutputs.get(iKey));
            }
        }
        messagesMap.put(curErrorMessage.errorName,curErrorMessage );
    }
}
```

It is not a clean solution, only the best I thought of. But it is not even good enough! Because if I want to localize the messages (it should be done, too), I have to repeat/translate the whole string-array of messages in every language variant. Only some messages that are meant to be localized. Technical ones remain English. So, repeating everything is bad.

XML resource won't help, because I need again repeat it as a whole in the every language variant. So, it is even worse.

Please, could you advise some smarter structure for reading Resources? And/or some other way for defining structured and localized resources?

P.S. The question doesn't contain a word on reflection, but I think that the solution very probably lies in that field. So I tagged it with reflection, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow nobody answered... And I have found a solution myself. It is not a new and clean solution. It only elaborates the previously described one. But it works.

I have simply divided error messages to two categories - that remain English and localizable ones. In code I pour them into one list. Localizable messages will be localized, constantly English will remain English. The bad news is that very hard controlling if all three divided (so, up to six) arrays will be mutually correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood your question but writing something because that perhaps help you.

You can put resources that never want to be localized to folder that not localized like 'values' all together only once. and

Resources that you want to be localized must put to folders that localized-matching folders like 'values-ko_KR'.

Also the id of resources must different between localized one and not one.

Then you can load all resources together into one map.

Am I misunderstood?