# Android App Lifecycle and Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having a bit of an issue with interaction beween my app and other apps on my phone, but I'm starting to think that maybe it's working as designed? Anyway, here's the problem.

My App, call it *App A* is a photo-manipulation app. So a user goes in, plays around to make changes and then uses the *Share* button to pass it on *(SEND Intent)*. The photo is sent to another app, chosen from the *Share* menu, call it *App B*. This stand-alone app has its own menus, completely different look and feel, etc. The user does his thing in this app for a bit, then hits the home button and goes his way to do something else.

Sometime later, he decides he wants to run my app again. He goes into the launcher, hits the icon for *App A* (my app), and up pops *App B*. Very confusing. If he happens to remember that last time he ran *App A*, he used the share button to get into *App B*, maybe he'll think to use the back button, to get back into *App A*. If he doesn't remember, all he knows is that he is trying to use *App A*, but Android is giving him *App B*.

(I have one app on my phone that takes over the back button for its own use so you more-or-less get stuck in *App B* with no way out. Ugh. You hit the icon for *App A* and always end up in *App B*)

Is there any solution to this, or is it working as designed? None of my onCreate, OnResume, onStart, etc. methods get called when this is second-open is occurring, so I can't trap it. And realistically, I can see the desire for this behavior when timelines are short - i.e. hit the home button, quickly use some other tool, and then go back to what you were doing. But with a timeline any longer than a minute or two, it gets very confusing.

Anybody else dealing with this problem? Is there a basic Android architectural issue here? Is the SEND intent being mis-used by being accepted by stand-alone apps instead of small utilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use Intent flag 'FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY'. It means starting intent never goes into activity stack.

Comment: Thanks lulmeya! I rant on for 300 words and you give me the solution in two sentences. Using that flag when I send my Intent seems to do the trick, but I'll do more testing to see if there are unintended consequences. And I still have the reverse problem, when you start in *App B* and send to *App A*. Is there a way to remove myself from the history stack?

Comment: It can be achieved with finish() method. That manually finishes the activity itself. It will be removed from the stack. I'm going to sleep now. Timezone may be different for us. I'm in midnight. see you tomorrow.

Comment: +1 You are really good! Very interesting things about the stack. Please, maybe you could help with three my questions? In two I had picked an answer, but it is not a real answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942415/why-linearlayout-instance-getlayoutparams-looks-to-have-a-wrong-class (has bounty), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788603/how-to-make-a-structured-and-localized-resource, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848121/why-it-is-impossible-to-access-resources-in-a-static-way. Beforehand grateful.

Comment: Testing with the "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY" flag reveals some unintended behaviors. It appears to work fine when dealing with two apps *App A* and *App B*, but if *A* sends to *B* and then *B* needs to send content to *C*, then on return from *C*, *A* gets control back since *B* isn't on the history stack. Oops... Not sure what to do about that.

Comment: Using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET - seems to be more like what I need. For discussion see: https://plus.google.com/u/0/108967384991768947849/posts/HUvfz58KSfQ

Comment: I was wondering about that flag. You cleared my wondering about that. It seems to be useful in many cases. Thanks.